# Apache Beam - Write BQ query result into multiple table in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm creating a dataflow pipeline. To minimize query cost, it is supposed to read a very big table in BigQuery (once), then write it into two destination tables in Cassandra.

I've successfully written the data to 1 table (DestinationTable1), but I have no idea how to add one more destination table (DestinationTable2). Here's my code:

```
@Table(keyspace = "ks", name = "DestinationTable1",
readConsistency = "LOCAL_QUORUM",
writeConsistency = "LOCAL_QUORUM",
caseSensitiveKeyspace = false,
caseSensitiveTable = false)
class DestinationTable1 implements Serializable{
    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name="mac")
    private String mac;
    @Column(name="site_id")
    private String site_id;

    public DestinationTable1(String mac, String site_id) {
        this.mac = mac;
        this.site_id = site_id;
    }
    
    public String getMac() { return mac; }
    public void setMac(String mac) {this.mac = mac; }

    public String getSite_id() { return site_id; }
    public void setSite_id(String site_id) { this.site_id = site_id; }
}

@Table(keyspace = "ks", name = "DestinationTable2",
readConsistency = "LOCAL_QUORUM",
writeConsistency = "LOCAL_QUORUM",
caseSensitiveKeyspace = false,
caseSensitiveTable = false)
class DestinationTable2 implements Serializable{
    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name="mac")
    private String mac;
    @Column(name="site_id")
    private String site_id;

    public DestinationTable2(String mac, String site_id) {
        this.mac = mac;
        this.site_id = site_id;
    }
    
    public String getMac() { return mac; }
    public void setMac(String mac) {this.mac = mac; }

    public String getSite_id() { return site_id; }
    public void setSite_id(String site_id) { this.site_id = site_id; }
}

public class CpmMacProfile {
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                // create and load default properties
                Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("app.config");
                defaultProps.load(in);
                in.close();

                Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

                /* Read from BQ using read(SerializableFunction) */
                PCollection<DestinationTable1> data =  p.apply("Read BigQuery",BigQueryIO.read(new SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, DestinationTable1>() {
                           public DestinationTable1 apply(SchemaAndRecord record) {
                                     GenericRecord r = record.getRecord();
                                     return new DestinationTable1(
                                                 (String) r.get("mac").toString(), (String) r.get("site_id").toString()
                                                 );
                                   }
                                 }).fromQuery("SELECT mac, site_id FROM `dataset.very_big_table` limit 10").usingStandardSql().withoutValidation());
                
                // Write to cassandra 1
                data.apply("Write Cassandra 1",CassandraIO.<DestinationTable1>write()
                    .withHosts(Arrays.asList(defaultProps.getProperty("app.cxnode1"), defaultProps.getProperty("app.cxnode2")))
                    .withPort(Integer.parseInt(defaultProps.getProperty("app.cxport")))
                    .withUsername(defaultProps.getProperty("app.cxuser"))
                    .withPassword(defaultProps.getProperty("app.cxpassword"))
                    .withKeyspace("system")
                    .withEntity(DestinationTable1.class));
                
                // Write to cassandra 2
                data.apply("Write Cassandra 2",CassandraIO.<DestinationTable2>write()
                    .withHosts(Arrays.asList(defaultProps.getProperty("app.cxnode1"), defaultProps.getProperty("app.cxnode2")))
                    .withPort(Integer.parseInt(defaultProps.getProperty("app.cxport")))
                    .withUsername(defaultProps.getProperty("app.cxuser"))
                    .withPassword(defaultProps.getProperty("app.cxpassword"))
                    .withKeyspace("system")
                    .withEntity(DestinationTable2.class));

                p.run();
        }
}
```

Under line **//Write Cassandra 2** I got error `The method apply(String, PTransform<? super PCollection<DestinationTable1>,OutputT>) in the type PCollection<DestinationTable1> is not applicable for the arguments (String, CassandraIO.Write<DestinationTable2>)`

Schema DestinationTable2 has the same structure as DestinationTable1.

Need advice please.

Comment: Have you ever tried by crating a new data instance? as you are returning the object only for DestinationTable1 in this part `public DestinationTable1 apply(SchemaAndRecord record)` .  You can test it and change to `DestinationTable2` instead of `DestinationTable1` references, I think it will write only in DestinationTable2

Comment: @Juls if I created a new data instance, it means I run the same query in BigQuery against the same table, doubling my query cost. All I need to do is run the query once and write them to multiple tables in Cassandra

Comment: Can you provide the pom.xml or the dependencies you are using please?